# Argument inside of input

Tags: python, list, input, arguments

**Very beginner question here!** I'm trying to create a program that asks for 5 game results, takes away the best and the worst one and counts the average on the ones that are left -> final result.

I think I got the math and the lists right, BUT I can't find a way to get a ***running number inside of the input***. (Example given in the #code comments.) I tried to look for a way to get this, but couldn't. Python says *"TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2"*. I understand it means that I can't put the serial number inside the input then?

Is there another way to create this? I tried to go around it with function-type solution already, but could not figure it out.

```
def main():

    round = 1

    performance_results = []

    while round < 6:
        time = float(input("Enter the time for performance: ", round))


        # "enter the time for performance 1:
        # "enter the time for performance 2:
        # "enter the time for performance 3: ... till the end of while


        performance_results.append(time)

        round += 1


    # max and min from the list
    max_result = (max(performance_results))
    min_result = (min(performance_results))

    # removes max and min from the list
    performance_results.remove(max_result)
    performance_results.remove(min_result)

    # sum from all the numbers left on the list
    sum = performance_results[0]+performance_results[1]+performance_results[2]

    # average from the results
    final_result = sum / 3

    print("The official competition score is", final_result,"seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to pass round as parameter to input function instead do the string formatting here.

try below code:

```
time = float(input("Enter the time for performance %s:" % round))
```

This will put value of round inside the string

TIP: round is python keyword you can use any other variable name instead of round

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
float(input(f"Enter the time for performance {round}:"))
```

And as Amit mentioned, don't use keywords such as `round` as var names.

Comment: Yes, it gives an error when it is there. But if I don't have anything there, how will it give the round number (performance 1, performance 2...etc)?

Comment: Do u wanna round the input?

Comment: Do u wanna round the float to an integer? Is that wht u wanna do?

Comment: I'm sorry english is not my native language so it might be awfully explained.. But it should look like in the comments I put below that part of code. User gives the result 5 times and each time INSIDE the question the number changes from 1 to 5. Like a serial number.

Comment: Oh got it. The first time, it should be Enter the time for the performance 1. For the 2nd time, it shd be Enter the time for the performance 2. Is that wht u want?

Answer (score 0):

If im interpreting this question correctly; you want to change the input it asks depending on the number, we can do this using string formatting!

Python has a few ways we can format strings (depending on your python version you may be limited to fewer)

**f-string formatting**
f strings are the equivelent of js's string litterals providing a very easy to read format and are notated by the `f` at the start of the string, note: for *python 3.6+ iirc*

```py
a = 123
b = "hello"
my_msg = f"{b} world, have some numbers: {a}"
print(my_msg)
# will give us as a response:
>>> hello world, have some numbers: 123
```

**format() method**
`str.format()` is a less readable than f strings but can be alot more useful in places.
they work for Python 3.x+ and use `{}` place holders

```py
a = 123
b = hello
my_msg = "{} world, have some numbers: {a}".format(b, a=a) # yes! you can use place holders to be used as kwargs.
print(my_msg)
# will give us as a response:
>>> hello world, have some numbers: 123
```

There are other methods of formatting however these are the most popular and people have already mentioned another example.